# How to make two python functions run on the same line

Tags: python

```
print("||") + os.system('PING -n 1 {} | FIND "TTL="'.format(host))
```

the output is:

```
  ||
  reply from {}: ms etc
```

is it possible to make it like this?

```
  || reply from {}: ms etc
```

Comment: What about ```print("||" + os.system('PING -n 1 {} | FIND "TTL="'.format(host)) )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the `end` parameter of your `print` from a new-line (the default) to an empty space
2. Flush the print so the `os.system` output will come after the `print`
3. Don't add `print` to `os.system` since `print` returns `None`

```py
import os

print("||", end='', flush=True)
os.system('PING -n 1 {} | FIND "TTL="'.format(host))
```